# If date is todays date display "today", or "yesterday"

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, shopify

In my Shopify blog I can display the date of the posted article by the following code:

```
{{ article.created_at | date: "%A, %-d. %B" }}
```

It displays like this: Friday, 22. January. [See date desc from Shopify here.](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/additional-filters#date)

Is it possible to make a script that checks if the date is today, then display the text "today" insted of the shopify date script? And "yesterday"?

Comment: there's also [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) Which has angular wrappers or just plain ol' JavaScript.

Comment: Can you add your own javascript? ... And how does the html element output look like for the displayed date?

Comment: @LGSon Yes I can add my own JavaScript.  `<span class="date">{{ article.created_at | date: "%A, %-d. %B" }}</span>` What shoudl I add?

Comment: you can use string filter to replace today's date value with 'Today' string over your date filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a built-in solution with Shopify, but if not, running this script after page load should give you a way to do what you want.

Note though, that the date to calc. need to have the year as well, or else it will go wrong.

---

*Update after request to not show the year*

To show the date without year, you could do like this instead, where you can format the visible date any way you like, as it uses the `data-date` value for calc.

A positive side effect with this is, that if you need the date it will still be there in the `data-date` attribute.

```
<span class="date" data-date='{{ article.published_at | date: "%F" }}'>{{ article.created_at | date: "%A, %-d. %B" }}</span>
```

*Updated sample*

```js
function makeYMD(d) {
  return d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d.getDate();
}
function getYesterday(d) {
  return new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1));
}

var span = document.querySelector('span.date');
var spandate = new Date(span.getAttribute("data-date"));
var today = new Date();
var yesterday = getYesterday(new Date());

spandate = makeYMD(spandate);
today = makeYMD(today);
yesterday = makeYMD(yesterday);


if(today == spandate) {
   span.textContent = "Today";
} else if(yesterday == spandate) {
   span.textContent = "Yesterday";
}
```

```html
<span class="date" data-date='2016-01-31'>Monday, 31. January</span>
```

Comment: Hm I see. Is it possible to have it not with the year?

Comment: @VemundEldegard Yes, I will update my answer soon with a suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one, using the [toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString):

```
function renderDate(date) {
  const today = new Date
  const yesterday = new Date; yesterday.setDate(today.getDate() - 1)
  if(date.toLocaleDateString() == today.toLocaleDateString()){
    return 'Today'
  }else if (date.toLocaleDateString() == yesterday.toLocaleDateString()) {
    return 'Yesterday'
  }
  return date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
    day : 'numeric',
    month : 'long'
  })
}
//Test:
renderDate(new Date('2016-11-11'))
"Today"
renderDate(new Date('2016-11-10'))
"Yesterday"
renderDate(new Date('2016-11-0'))
"Invalid Date"
renderDate(new Date('2016-11-5'))
"November 5"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Control Flow Tags](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/tags/control-flow-tags#elsif-else) to achieve this.

```
  {%if {{article.created_at|date: "%Y %b %d"}}== {{ 'now' | date: "%Y %b %d" }} %}
       Today
    {% else %}
    Yesterday
      {% endif %}
```

Comment: I guess this could work. However the code here doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Test here https://jsfiddle.net/027jch3z/

```
var now = new Date;
function today( created_at_day,created_at_month,created_at_year, now ){
 return created_at_day== now.getUTCDate() &&
         created_at_month == (now.getUTCMonth()+1) &&
         created_at_year == now.getUTCFullYear();
}

// for yesterday, do some calculation here,
var yest = new Date(now);
yest = new Date(yest.setDate(d.getDate() -1));

function yesterday( created_at_day,created_at_month,created_at_year, yest )
{
  return created_at_day == yest.getUTCDate() &&
         created_at_month == (yest.getUTCMonth() +1) &&
         created_at_year == yest.getUTCFullYear();
}


//test calls
alert("Today: "+today(1,2,2016,now));
alert("Yesterday: "+yesterday(31,1,2016,yest));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an AngularJS filter that will do that. See an example here:

Demo: https://www.screencast.com/t/rh609WQI6

Code: https://codepen.io/skounis/pen/PKPKGw

```
.filter('tyday', function($filter) {
  return function(input, pattern) {
    if (!pattern) {
                pattern = 'EEEE, MMM d';
            }
            var today = $filter('date')(new Date(), pattern);

            var yday = new Date();
            yday.setDate(yday.getDate() - 1);
            var yesterday = $filter('date')(yday, pattern);

            if (input === today) {
                return 'Today';
            }

            if (input === yesterday) {
                return 'Yesterday';
            }

            return input;
  };
});
```